# Is it possible to use data cleansing in SQL Server by using Azure ML?

Tags: sql-server, data-cleaning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a SQL Server which I want to run data cleansing every night. To do this I want to use Azure Machine Learning.

To my question; Is it possible to run data cleansing with Azure Machine Learning directly in my SQL Server?

Comment: yes, we can perform data cleansing. Refer the sample link provided. The datastore considered in the example is CSV, instead of that file, we can replace the SQL server repository data. 
https://www.sqlshack.com/data-cleansing-in-azure-machine-learning/

Comment: The datastore can be connected to the ML service while creating the pipeline. We can create the datastore connection with respect to the compute instances. Assign the SQL server details while connecting to the data store.